# Scala toMap type conversion issue

Tags: scala, type-conversion

I have following simplified code to represent the compilation issue I am facing with scala toMap conversion.

Code

```
def test() : Option[Map[String, String]] = {
val someMap = Map("" -> List.empty[String] )
someMap
  .get("")
  .flatMap(_.headOption)
  .map { span =>
    val map = mutable.Map.empty[String, String]
    map.toMap
  }}
```

I get this error

> polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;  found
>   : [T, U]scala.collection.immutable.Map[T,U]  required:
>   scala.collection.concurrent.Map[String,String]
>           map.toMap

Not sure how to resolve this. I cannot change the return type of function as its expected to return the `Option[Map[String, String]]`

thanks,
Sandy

Comment: Compiles without problems on 2.12.4. What version are you using? The error message with "required: concurrent.Map" looks odd. Are you sure that your example actually reproduces the error?

Comment: I am on 2.12.1. And I do get compile error as mentioned above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After importing `scala.collection.mutable`, your code does compile. The error you get states that your test function expects a return of type `scala.collection.concurrent.Map[String,String]`. The only reason why that I can think of is that you have imported `scala.collection.concurrent.Map` somewhere before the declaration of your function.

As a consequence, the immutable.Map type is masked by the concurrent.Map type and by simply using "Map" you actually declared a return of type `Option[scala.collection.concurrent.Map[String, String]]`, hence your compilation error.

Try removing the import or using the full path in your return type declaration (`scala.collection.immutable.Map`).

Comment: I have  these in my imports - import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import scala.collection.concurrent.Map
import scala.collection.mutable

Comment: This is where the error comes from. scala.collection.immutable.Map is imported by default but if you import another one (here scala.collection.concurrent.Map), it get masked by this new Map type. I edited my answer to provide solutions.

Comment: yup I used explicit type for concurrent Map and removed its import. solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `immutable` Map in the return type but, returning mutable.Map

```
  def test() : Option[Map[String, String]] = {

    val someMap = Map("" -> List.empty[String] )

    someMap
      .get("")
      .flatMap(_.headOption)
      .map { span =>
        Map.empty[String, String]
      }
 }
```

Comment: ok so in actual code I want to modify mao before I return it. And retnrn type expects a mutable map